# Oracle creating sequences with execute immediate

Tags: sql, oracle

This might have already been asked but I am not able to resolve it, so posting again.

I need to create an oracle sequence with the start value coming from a variable. So obviously I need to use execute immediate for the same within a pl/sql block.

I used the following PL/SQL block to create the sequence:

```
declare nl_seqmax NUMBER :=0; 
BEGIN 
  SELECT 1000000009 
      into nl_seqmax 
  from dual; 
  if nl_seqmax > 0 THEN 
      execute immediate 'CREATE SEQUENCE my_seq INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH '||nl_seqmax || ' MAXVALUE 4000000000 CACHE 20 ORDER'; 
  end if; 
end; 
/ 

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

But later when referencing this sequence, I see that it throws 942 error.

```
SQL> AUDIT GRANT ON my_seq  BY ACCESS WHENEVER SUCCESSFUL;

ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

Any idea on this ? Should all the references to sequence also should use dynamic sql ?

Comment: Could you please post your oracle sequence creation script? I doubt that you used create sequence "my_seq"!!

Comment: declare
    nl_seqmax NUMBER :=0;
    BEGIN
    SELECT 1000000009 into nl_seqmax from dual;
    if nl_seqmax > 0
    THEN
    execute immediate 'CREATE SEQUENCE my_seq INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH '||nl_seqmax || ' MAXVALUE 4000000000 CACHE 20 ORDER';
    end if;
    end;
   /

Comment: This error indicates that at the moment you are trying to execute `audit` command there is no sequence `my_seq` in your schema. Check if it has been created

Comment: Please don't post code in comments.

Comment: I see the following response after some googling, is it true ? Then how should we resolve such issues :The procedure can't compile because the sequence doesn't exist at compile time. Oracle can not tell that you're going to create it using dynamic sql.
For this to work all code that references the sequence would have to be dynamic sql as well.
My advise - don't create the sequence dynamically, just create it normally or you'll keep running into problems like this.

Comment: I see that no issues if run the scripts from the same schema. Could you please confirm you do the create and access from same schema? I am afraid that you are using two different schemas which  might be creating the problem